# Bep20 OpenZeppelin Token Unable to Verify

Tags: remix

I created one token on bep20 chain and I am starting to like it, but I am unable to verify. I am pretty new to that and I hope I haven't missed something that cannot be fixed. So the token is 0x0005fd45281d89042965acbaf645ecc86bc5ec5c and the creation hash is 0xe204201e04ceb186fd86ef86269f825a8aa67ae08a9aa73c961ac2e93b4a219b
you can check it here: https://bscscan.com/tx/0xe204201e04ceb186fd86ef86269f825a8aa67ae08a9aa73c961ac2e93b4a219b

the code from remix that I used to create is this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.1;
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
contract DIAMOND is ERC20 {
    constructor(uint256 initialSupply) public ERC20("1DIAMOND","1DIA") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 7 + initialSupply + 7);
    }
}
```

Any help will be greatly greatly appreciated, because this really killed my enthusiasm on the topic.

Comment: RESOLVED. I found a similar contract created on a similar date and copied the IERC open zepelin stuff and changed the part with my contract creation code extending ERC20 class.

Comment: Can you help what you change or did to verify?

Comment: yes I had to add all of the imported files manually in my main file and selected "single file contract"